# How to select a row based on its row number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a small project in which I'll need to select a record from a temporary table based on the actual row number of the record.

How can I select a record based on its row number?

Comment: Did you Google for "`row_number()` function in sql"? What is your sql-server version?

Comment: Actually records in tables do not have numbers. Until you set `ORDER BY` in your query row numbering does not apply.

Comment: If you're using SQL 2012 leverage the sequence command in a column.  Trust me, it's a life saver.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A couple of the other answers touched on the problem, but this might explain. There really isn't an order implied in SQL (set theory). So to refer to the "fifth row" requires you to introduce the concept

```
Select *
From 
(
    Select 
      Row_Number() Over (Order By SomeField) As RowNum
    , *
    From TheTable
) t2
Where RowNum = 5
```

In the subquery, a row number is "created" by defining the order you expect. Now the outer query is able to pull the fifth entry out of that ordered set.

Comment: How do we achieve the same in mySQL?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan, not very familiar with mySQL, but looks like it supports much the same window functions (link ROW_NUMBER). So I think you can try to do the same thing. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 6):

Technically SQL Rows do not have "RowNumbers" in their tables.  Some implementations (Oracle, I think) provide one of their own, but that's not standard and SQL Server/T-SQL does not.  You can add one to the table (sort of) with an IDENTITY column.

Or you can add one (for real) in a query with the ROW_NUMBER() function, but unless you specify your own unique ORDER for the rows, the ROW_NUMBERS will be assigned non-deterministically.

Comment: You are probably referring to Oracle's `ROWID` which is not a row "number" but the physical address of the row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, that was it.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the `row_number()` function, as Kaf mentioned in the comments.

Here is an example:

```
WITH MyCte AS 
(
    SELECT   employee_id,
             RowNum = row_number() OVER ( order by employee_id )
    FROM     V_EMPLOYEE 
    ORDER BY Employee_ID
)
SELECT  employee_id
FROM    MyCte
WHERE   RowNum > 0
```

Comment: Worked great, ty.  Except I had to remove the ORDER BY Employee_ID to get it to run (the one at the bottom of the WITH statement)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways of doing this.

Suppose u have an employee table with the columns as `emp_id`, `emp_name`, `salary`. You need the top 10 employees who has highest salary.

1. Using `row_number()` analytic function

   ```
   Select * from
   ( select emp_id,emp_name,row_number() over (order by salary desc) rank
   from employee)
   where rank<=10
   ```
2. Using `rank()` analytic function

   ```
   Select * from
   ( select emp_id,emp_name,rank() over (order by salary desc) rank
   from employee)
   where rank<=10
   ```
3. Using `rownum`

   ```
   select * from
   (select * from employee order by salary desc)
   where rownum<=10;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the rows of the table without being re-ordered by some set of values:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT '1')) AS RowID, * FROM #table
```

Answer (score 2):

If using SQL Server 2012 you can now use offset/fetch:

```
declare @rowIndexToFetch int
set @rowIndexToFetch = 0

select
    * 
from 
    dbo.EntityA ea
order by
    ea.Id
offset @rowIndexToFetch rows
fetch next 1 rows only
```

Comment: Or you can just use the sequence command and create a column of unique numbers.

Comment: Brilliant, that's so much simpler than the row_number(), but keep in mind this does not keep track of rows inserted at runtime. e.g. this is not thread safe