# What is the sql server 2008 query to retrieve records from a sql view based on the row numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

If I have  a sql view  consisting  of  1000 records ,I want to retrieve  records between rownumber  20 and  500.  What  is the query to do this ?

Or

Is there a way  to  add a column like rownumber  in the view ?

Comment: this question has been answered before  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164698/how-to-select-a-row-based-on-its-row-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use row_number function available in SQL for that, like

```
WITH tbl AS
(
    SELECT
       .. ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ..) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        yourtable
)
SELECT
    ..
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN 20 AND 500
```

**updates:**

Regarding performance of the query, please check this one too,

```
    select .. from (SELECT
      .. , Row_Number() over (order by ..) as rownumber

    FROM
        yourtable) as A
where
    rownumber BETWEEN 20 AND 500
```

hope this helps.

Comment: But  this query is little clumsy  when  performance  is  considered  , since it  loads  the entire view  into the table  'tbl'  and again executing select query   over the  'tbl' .

Comment: The updated query seems to take  more  Sql server execution time than the  former query.