# Grouping in a report

Tags: t-sql

I am using t-sql.

I have 4 work trays and I would like a report that gives me the name of each work tray, plus the oldest item of post in it, plus a couple more fields. It needs to be limited to 4 rows - one for each work tray.

So at the moment I have this:

```
SELECT WorkTray, MIN(Date) AS [OldestDate], RefNo, NameofItem

FROM ...

GROUP BY WorkTray,RefNo, NameofItem

ORDER BY WorkTray,RefNo, NameofItem
```

However when I run this it gives me every item in each work tray, eg a report 100s of items long - I just want it to be limited to 4 rows of data, one for each work tray:

```
Work Tray    Date                    RefNo                    NameofItem

A                 1/2/15                25                          Outstanding Bill

B                 5/5/18                1000                      Lost post

C                 2/2/12               17                          Misc

D                 6/12/17              876                       Misc
```

So I'm sure I'm going wrong somewhere with my GROUP BY - but I can't see where.

Comment: Well RefNo and NameofItem must not be unique per work tray.... so you can't do this... What if there are two rows with different RefNo's per one work tray, what would you like displayed in the RefNo column?

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick for doing this that has been [answered on stackoverflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164698/how-to-select-a-row-based-on-its-row-number). Here it is adapted to your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT WorkTray, Date AS [OldestDate], RefNo, NameofItem, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkTray ORDER BY WorkTray, [Date]) AS rn
FROM MyTable
) GroupedByTray
WHERE rn = 1
```

The PARTITION BY tells it to count the rows for each type of tray, and the ORDER BY works similar to the normal ORDER BY clause. Assuming you have only 4 work trays (A - D), the "WHERE rn = 1" part will return only the first row for WorkTrays A - D.

Comment: Thanks. I used a CTE along similar lines: WITH cte

as

(

SELECT WorkTray, Date AS [OldestDate], RefNo, NameofItem,

row_number() over (partition by WorkTray order by WorkTray,RefNo, NameofItem) RN

FROM ...

GROUP BY WorkTray,RefNo, NameofItem

) select * from cte where rn=1

Comment: @WillF Note - This will get only the OLDEST RefNo and NameofItem for each of the Work Trays... This may or may not be what you want, depending what RefNo is